# Ethernet PHY design query: Compatibility of DP83848QSQ/NOPB with STM32F407VET6 and pin configuration concerns

Tags: stm32, ethernet, emc, emi-filtering, phy

I'm relatively new to Ethernet PHY design and currently working on a project where I've chosen the [DP83848QSQ](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dp83848q-q1.pdf)/NOPB PHY and plan to connect it to the STM32F407VET6 microcontroller.

However, I've encountered an issue where pin number 32 on the PHY doesn't seem to have a corresponding pin configuration on the STM32F407VET6. I'm uncertain if my design is correct and whether it will effectively function as intended.

My primary objectives are to ensure the functionality of this design and to subsequently pass EMC and EMI tests.

Could someone experienced in Ethernet PHY design and STM32 microcontrollers provide guidance on how to improve my design and address the pin configuration discrepancy? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

[image: PCB Design]

[image: STM32F407VET6]

[image: A829-1A1T-91B RJ45]

Comment: At least the ESD protection doesn't work since it's not on PHY ground. If it helps, you can think that your device and the other device, or even your device and the cable, could have 1000 VDC or 1000 VAC between them, and it must still work.

Comment: While the dp83848 is a well proven chip, it is older and expensive and probably power hungry, you might consider something newer if still in the design stage..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32nd pin is the MII/RMII selector and RX_DV (Receive - Data Valid) pin.

The pin has a pull-down to make the default setting 0 (MII mode). If you tie the pin to VDD with a pull-up the mode will RMII. So first you should decide if you need to go for MII or RMII. I haven't checked the entire ethernet functionality of the MCU if it has both MII (25 MHz) and RMII (50 MHz) support, or MII by default. But it appears to be MII by default.

The corresponding pin on STM32F407 is `PA7` which has the `ETH_MII_RX_DV` alternate pin function. So the 32nd pin of the PHY goes to PA7 of the MCU.

Some other things that my eyes have caught:

- I don't see any clock connection. The PHY provides RX and TX clocks so those should be connected to the MCU's `PA1` and `PC3` pins, respectively. These pins appear to have the `MII_RX_CLK` and `MII_TX_CLK` alternate functions. Check the datasheet for details.
- MII and RMII require synchronisation with either 25 MHz (MII) or 50 MHz (RMII). The clock can be generated by the MCU and supplied to the PHY's oscillator input pin(s). Check the MCU's MCO1 and MCO2 functionalities.
- I see ferrite beads on the supply lines of the PHY. Be careful with using them as [you may end up with broken PHYs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558423/unplugging-ethernet-cable-leads-an-abnormal-power-supply-fail).

Comment: I Want to use RMII Mode of the PHY

Comment: @Alirezaagha30 then you'll need to tie RX_DV pin of the PHY to 3V3 with a resistor. (pull-up) Something between 1k and 3k3 should work. And also you'll have to configure the MCU accordingly.

Comment: Can you please see my PCB layout too? I use 6-layer PCB and use the top layer and bottom layer for routing the PHY.

Comment: @Alirezaagha30 it's difficult to understand just by looking at it. For ethernet the differential impedance of each pair from magnetics to PHY should be 100 Ohms and each individual trace of the pair should be 50 Ohms (this means 50 Ohms single-ended and 100 Ohms differential). For the MII/RMII lanes each trace should have 50 Ohms single-ended impedance. Also, avoid vias as much as you can. And finally, read the app notes and datasheets for layout considerations/tips. That's all I can say.